# Querying array in hazelcast jsonvalues

Tags: arrays, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am trying to search HazelcastJsonValue, data example for the same.

```
class A {
 B[] listOfB;
}

class B {
 int num;
 String name;
}
```

'A' object is  present in Hazelcast as HazelcastJsonValue and i want to create query which fetches all objects which contain B for which num = 10 and name = test 
hazelcast query for array search using predicate

```
Predicate.equal("listOfB[any].name","test")
```

for above scenario query i can make using predicates

```
Predicate[] arrayOfPredicate = {Predicates.equal("listOfB[any].num",10)
                ,Predicates.equal("listOfB[any].name","test")};
Predicate p = Predicates.and(arrayOfPredicate);
System.out.println(p.toString()); // (listOfB[any].num=10 AND listOfB[any].name=test)
```

Example Data in hazelcast

```
[
  {
    "listOfB": [
      {
        "num": 10,
        "name": "ab"
      },
      {
        "num": 11,
        "name": "test"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "listOfB": [
      {
        "num": 10,
        "name": "test"
      },
      {
        "num": 12,
        "name": "xyz"
      }
    ]
  },
{
    "listOfB": [
      {
        "num": 30,
        "name": "abc"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Hazelcast query for same

(listOfB[any].num=10 AND listOfB[any].name=test)
But this is not giving desired results instead below result came

```
[
  {
    "listOfB": [
      {
        "num": 10,
        "name": "ab"
      },
      {
        "num": 11,
        "name": "test"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "listOfB": [
      {
        "num": 10,
        "name": "test"
      },
      {
        "num": 12,
        "name": "xyz"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Desired results are

```
{
  "listOfB": [
    {
      "num": 10,
      "name": "test"
    },
    {
      "num": 12,
      "name": "xyz"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can i get desired results?

Answer (score 0):

Both of the above should've been returned in your result set.  Is this not the case?  The fact that you're wanting *any* will return true for the above data.  If you limited the filter to listOfB[0], then the 2nd will be returned but I'm sure your intention is to not limit to 1st item only.

Comment: I have explained myself with data set now, desired result is to get objects of A which has at-least one object of B who satisfy required condition. In accordance to data example it should be only 1 object of A. @ Manny David

Comment: With your current model, your only other option is:  (listOfB[0].num=10 AND listOfB[0].name=test) but this is will not work for, say, num=12,& name=xyz.  Perhaps you can have another look at your model to see if there are other differentiating attributes.

Comment: This is just an example, need solution without referring fixed values
@ Manny David